Twilio Flex Unified Profile's History feature not working properly
I am trying to implement History feature in my Twilio Flex. This feature comes under Unified Profiles (which is under Beta version).
I have uploaded dummy users list containing phone number, email, first name, last name of the user.
Issue is that for incoming message to agent, it is showing history communication done via web chat, sms only (Not including calls traces) & similarly during the incoming call to agent, it is showing only history of calls only (Not sms or web chat traces).
Ideally, it should show history of all communication channels (ie: SMS, Call, WebChat).
What could be the potential issue ?
Thanks!
